# ion-fab button overlaps other ion components

Tags: ionic-framework, button, styling

I am using a ion-fab list to hold a ion-fab button but the issue is the ion-fab button overlaps the ion-list (date picker below)  / ion-button regardless of applying inline margin styles, ion-item-dividers, css external styles etc.

How can I separate the ion-fab content for content directly above and below ?

[image]

This is the styling:

```
<!--End Date Pciker-->
    <ion-list >
      <ion-accordion-group >
        <ion-accordion #myAccordion value="start">
          <ion-item slot="header">
            <ion-label >End Date</ion-label>
            <ion-note slot="end" id="datetimeValue">{{selectedEndDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</ion-note>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-datetime
            id="datetime"
            displayFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
            slot="content"
            presentation="date"
            min="01-01-1980"
            max="31-01-2100"
            
            [(ngModel)]="selectedEndDate"
            name="selectedEndDate"
           
          ></ion-datetime>
        </ion-accordion>
      </ion-accordion-group>
    </ion-list>


<!-- Button for Capturing Photo , try ion-fab first-->

<ion-item-divider></ion-item-divider>

<ion-fab vertical="center" horizontal="center" slot="fixed">get cert 
  <ion-fab-button (click)="getCertficatePhoto()">
    <ion-icon name="camera"></ion-icon>
  </ion-fab-button>
</ion-fab>



    <ion-button style="margin-top: 20px;" fill="outline" expand="block"
    color="primary" type="submit">{{editEvent ? 'Update' : 'ADD'}}</ion-button>
      </form>

  </ion-content>
```

Comment: if you want to have camera button after date picker simply use ion-button fab button is position absolute buttons. check ion button and its css to make it look like fab.

Answer (score 1):

Use the ion-fab tag and only use the ion-fab-button. of course you will need to stylize it.